# CQRS Command Constructs

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I have a CQRS command like this

```
public sealed class RequestRoute
{
    public RequestRoute(string fromAddressName, double fromLatitude, double fromLongitude, string toAddressName, double toLatitude, double toLongitude, string userId)
    {
        UserId = userId;
        ToLongitude = toLongitude;
        ToLatitude = toLatitude;
        ToAddressName = toAddressName;
        FromLongitude = fromLongitude;
        FromLatitude = fromLatitude;
        FromAddressName = fromAddressName;
    }

    public string FromAddressName { get; private set; }
    public double FromLatitude { get; private set; }
    public double FromLongitude { get; private set; }

    public string ToAddressName { get; private set; }
    public double ToLatitude { get; private set; }
    public double ToLongitude { get; private set; }

    public string UserId { get; private set; }
}
```

My programmer's intuition tells me that I should factor the FromXXX and ToXXX fields into a separate class called "Address"...but I'm not sure if that violates the CQRS pattern... All of the examples I've seen use only primitive types as properties of commands and events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my money, there's no real value in such a refactoring.

Writing `route.ToLatitude` or `route.To.Latitude` does not change anything neither in readability nor during maintenance.

However, I would change the `double` **field** to a `decimal` (or even a to string) to avoid any problem while moving the DTO serialization (be it binary or not) between different platforms, machines or architectures.

Answer (score 8):

A command is data-oriented, not object-oriented. Its properties should be mostly primitives. You're not modeling anything here, just sending flat data around.

Using custom types forces you to publish the types to every client that wants to use the commands. It will also prevent you from changing these types in the future without some hassle.

Then there's seriazability: The less custom types the simpler.

In messages like commands and events I'd go with primitives as far as reasonably possible. Duplication is not the issue here, you want low coupling, serializability, change tolerance.

Comment: What if the command contains a collection of types with two or more primitives, for example List<SimpleDto>()?

Comment: It still is data-oriented. It doesn't encapsulate data and expose behavior. Basically a command is (or should be) just schema.

Comment: What would you use if your command would need a list of complex objects? Would you mark this complex object as serializable and then use List<SimpleDto> or would you use List<Tuple<string, string>>?

Comment: I would try to model the command so that it doesn't need complex objects in the first place. See my original answer.

Comment: +1, DTO-as are data structures (according to uncle Ben) and you follow a procedural approach by processing them. You need DTOs like commands, queries, events to decouple the domain logic from other parts of the application.

Comment: I agree in principle that serialization of a dto with nothing but primitives would be simpler. But I also fail to see how having 'complex types' (which in *this case* are just a simple nesting of primitives), really affects serialization, coupling or change tolerance in any tangible way. I would agree if it were a complex type containing behaviour such as validation, business rules, or dependencies from all over the place. But *in this case* it's still just a plain old dto, even with the nested type that is wrapping up a few primitives.

Comment: IMO, portability of the type, serialization, and change tolerance don't seem to be taking any kind of a hit here. I'm not sure why this answer is so popular. Even putting CQRS aside, dto's can have nesting without creating any real portability or serialization issues.

Answer (score 4):

Pattern-wise, it seems fine to extract a common type there. The overall concern is that commands should not change once issued, so just ensure the address type is immutable (as are the primitive types).

There may be some implementation constraints to consider, i.e. serialization.

Answer (score 1):

You are safe to refactor "To" and "From" into a class. Commands are the API to your domain, so as long as you can maintain it - you should be good.

P.S. If you'd ask the same question about Events in Event Sourcing - the answer would've been much more complicated

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a tiny bit of confusion here. CQRS simply means to have separate read and 'write' (behaviour rich) models. The RequestRoute is a command, thus a message and not a model. CQRS can be used with a message driven architecture but it's not required so these two aren't related.

In this case, you're right, FromXXX and ToXXX should be an Address class, however this has nothing to do with CQRS, so you're not violating anything.

Btw, a message should contain all the required information needed by its handler so you can put a lot of things in it, the only problem is serialization if you know the messages are going to be persisted, but a message is nothing more than a DTO anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with extracting a common type here. For the most part, you should be sharing schema rather than type, so it doesn't cause problems in that regard.